# Add 2nd domain on heroku resolving in sub folder

Tags: heroku, dns, amazon-route53

I'm not a DNS expert but manage to understand Route 53 + heroku quite ok now. I use a custom domain with route 53 and my main herokuapp. Now my app includes a side-project which I want to add another custom domain for, so in fact that would be a 2nd domain which resolves into a sub folder of my original app.

For this I created a 2nd hosted zone on Route 53, entered the name servers as usual. All like in the guide here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53 with the difference that I entered the sub folder of my app into the CNAME record set: http://myapp.herokuapp.com/path-to-my-side-project/

I also added the domain via heroku domains:add www.my-side-project.com

I get this when visiting the Domain in the Browser:

> The server at www.my-side-project.com can't be found, because the DNS
>   lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's
>   name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by
>   having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It
>   can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall
>   preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

Is there anything else I did not think off?

Comment: `Does not work.` is a little bit vague.

Comment: Sorry. I have amended my post.